# Django | I want to show the page to 'AnonymousUser' even though I'm using request.user in views.py

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to show the page to all users even if they are not logged in but because im using `request.user` in `views.py` this is not possible.

Is there anyway to handle this?

**views.py:**

```
class ServerView(View):
def get(self, request, server_tag):
    server = Server.objects.get(tag=server_tag)
    posts = server.posts.all()
    is_following = False
    relation = ServerFollow.objects.filter(server=server, user=request.user)
    if relation.exists():
        is_following = True
    return render(request, 'servers/server.html', {'server':server, 'posts':posts, 'is_following':is_following})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the request user is authenticated. Based on that you can implement chained filtering.

```
class ServerView(View):
    def get(self, request, server_tag):
        server = Server.objects.get(tag=server_tag)
        posts = server.posts.all()
        is_following = False
        qs = ServerFollow.objects.filter(server=server)
        if qs and request.user.is_authenticated():
            qs = qs.filter(user=request.user)
        if qs:
            is_following = True
        return render(request, 'servers/server.html', {'server':server, 'posts':posts, 'is_following':is_following})
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed my problem though you should change `is_authenticated()` to `is_authenticated`